# ePub is not defined in futurepress/epub.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Just started using the FuturePress/epub.js. And use with vue.js

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="/static/epub.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/libs/zip.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div onclick="Book.prevPage();">‹</div>
        <div id="area"></div>
        <div onclick="Book.nextPage();">›</div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

in `script.js`

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    created: function () {
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            var Book = ePub("http://desq.xyz/epub-test/book.epub");
            Book.renderTo("area");
        })
    }
});
```

However, an error occurs. `ReferenceError: ePub is not defined`. What is it??

Comment: Did you try `window.epub` ?

Answer (score 4):

It works ok with some mods (I am following examples given on epubjs repo)

- Using cdn for current `epub.min.js` (perhaps you don't have /static folder set correctly?)
- Using `jszip` as this is the one recommended by epubjs (zipjs may work also)
- Using Vue's data property to hold `rendition` and setting the click handlers to methods. May not be necessary, but without it you need click listeners and this is the (simpler) Vue way.
- Used an ebook from epubjs's samples as I'm not sure about the one you try to access.

This is a sample `index.html` that works. Just paste the code into a local file and open it with a browser.

**index.html**

```js
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/epubjs/dist/epub.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div @click="prev()">‹</div>
      <div id="area"></div>
    <div @click="next()">›</div>
  </span>
  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        book: null,
        rendition: null
      },
      created() {
        this.book = ePub("https://s3.amazonaws.com/epubjs/books/alice/OPS/package.opf");
        this.rendition = this.book.renderTo("area", {width: 600, height: 400});
        var displayed = this.rendition.display();
      },
      methods: {
        prev() {
          this.rendition.prev();
        },
        next() {
          this.rendition.next();
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This one doesn't work for me, my server log says I am missing css/stylesheet.css images/title.jpg and /images/plate01_th.jpg

Answer (score 2):

`epub.min.js` was not working for me when used from public CDNs.

After cloning library's [repository](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/) and compiling `dist` files, it seems to be working as expected.

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aBiscuit/cwep0mn7/8/) with your code and `epub.min.js` from own source.

So the issue is in correct `epub.min.js` file.

Build your own by following instructions on lib's [repository](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/) (**prefered way**) or feel free to [download](https://abiscuit.io/files/epub.min.js) temporarily available compiled source.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found that epub.js file from the so- called "prepared build" (by running command npm run prepare as describe [here](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/#building-for-distribution)) was not being loaded in my HTML file. I fixed the path problem and also resolved this one.